# Apache with Typecho and wordpress in a subdirectory --"No input file specified."

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to move my site from wordpress to Typecho(This is a china CMS system) by change my VirtualHost in `http.conf`.To be more clearly,follow is the doc tree in my server.

```
|-yjdata
      |-www(where I want my site to be direct to)
         |-php-fpm-5.5.conf
         |-wordpress(where my site is used to be direct to)
            |-index.php
            |-wp-admin
            |-... ...
         |-typecho
            |-index.php
            |-install.php
            |-... ...
```

Before my `http.conf` looked like this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com mydomain.com 
    DocumentRoot /yjdata/www/wordpress/
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:10000/yjdata/www/wordpress/$1
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Then I changed it as follow:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com mydomain.com 
    DocumentRoot /yjdata/www/
    ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:10000/yjdata/www/$1
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

I also created a index.html file in the `/www/` directory to show that if the set  take effect and a `php5.ini`

```
// index file
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Congratulations！</title>
</head>
<body>
    Coming final.QAQ
    <a href="./wordpress/index.php">wordpress</a>
    <a href="./typecho/index.php">typecho</a>
</body>
</html>
```

`php5.ini`

```
cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
```

Well, after restart my apache and change some static links in DataBase`wordpress` , the index file do take effect. And I also can get in the back-end pages and the artical's pages without being redirected by wordpress.
However, while I tried to entry this link `www.mydomain.com/typecho/`or`www.mydomain.com/typecho/install.php`, I still got "No input file specified." 
I guess it maybe due to the loss of `.htaccess`.So I created a `.htaccess`file in the`typecho` file directory but still got the same message.
This is the content of `.htaccess`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

Options +ExecCGI
addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
Header set Set-Cookie "language=%{lang}e; path=/;" env=lang
</IfModule>
```

By the way, in the Network tools in Chrome, I found that while I'm entrying the`www.mydomain.com/typecho/` link, it sent the cookie of wordpress, I used burp to clear it, but still no change.
The follow is what I also tried but useless.

In `php.ini` file.
Change `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` to `cgi.fix_pathinfo=1`

And in the end, this is the final doctree in my server.

```
|-yjdata
      |-www(where I want my site to be direct to)
         |-index.html
         |-php5.ini
         |-php-fpm-5.5.conf
         |-wordpress(where my site is used to be direct to)
            |-index.php
            |-wp-admin
            |-... ...
         |-typecho
            |-.htaccess
            |-php5.ini
            |-index.php
            |-install.php
            |-... ...
```

I have spent a whole day in this issue but still is failed.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm not sure the `path_info` part is pass with `ProxyPassMatch`. The regexp does not accept it.

Comment: I tried these way below. Change ` ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:10000/yjdata/www/$1` to ` ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:10000/yjdata/www/wordpress/$1`, and while entry`www.myadmin.com`, I get in`www/wordpress/`. Change it to ` ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php)$ fcgi://127.0.0.1:10000/yjdata/www/typecho/$1` and I still got `No input file specified.`  Try to delete it, and I got a `403 forbidden`.

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html#examples the path_info part is included there. `^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$`